# Conditional select in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

This is my situation in a excel file:

```
A          B        C       D
foo        x                x
bar                 x       x
example    x        x       x 
another    x
```

I would like to select for each row that has an x-value in column D, the value of the corresponding field in column A, and columns B and C only if there is the x-value in them.
So in this specific example the formula must give me back:

```
foo B
bar C
example B C
```

Is it possible? how?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter on each column. Filter Column D first with just 'x' showing, then Column B and C removing the blanks. After filtering you can select all cells you need and press (ALT + ;) to select just the shown cells/rows.

If you want the formula here it is:

```
=IF(AND(D2="x",B2="x",C2="x"),A2&" B C",IF(AND(D2="x",B2="x",C2=""),A2&" B",IF(AND(D2="x",B2="",C2="x"),A2&" C","")))
```

[image]

Comment: is possible do it with a formula?

Comment: If you want to put the concatenated values of the selection in a different cell? This is the formula if you put it in Column E:
=IF(AND(D2="x",B2="x",C2="x"),A2&" B C",IF(AND(D2="x",B2="x",C2=""),A2&" B",IF(AND(D2="x",B2="",C2="x"),A2&" C","")))

Comment: but if i filter in this way got only the row in with colum B,C,D has the value x

Comment: Did you change the cell references because my formula reference all points to row 2? Mine works fine.

Comment: i have the same xml structure, unfortunaly i get an error, but in any case I don't think the formula is correct because from the screen I see that you got only example BC, just as I said, but not the other cases.

Comment: My formula is definitely correct. How else would it work on the screenshot. You didn't say there were other cases. You only specified B and C. You gotta be specific, otherwise, use this answer and go from there. Thanks.

Comment: I specified the list that had to be returned in my question